# Segmentation fault in a C++ program when compiling with g++ using -O3

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++

When I compile the following piece of code with g++ (version 4.9.1), it works fine for non-optimization or optimization with -O2. However, when compiling with -O3 the program crashes at line 30 and prints "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I've tried to keep this a simple as possible. I also noticed, that removing (seemingly) unimportant parts, such as the member variable words, seems to resolve the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

char *curMemPos2=NULL;  //The first free pos in allocated memory

class Dictionary{
    public:
        int numWords;
        int* words;
        double* wordFrequency;
        Dictionary(int nw){
            numWords = nw;
            wordFrequency = NULL;
            wordFrequency = (double*)curMemPos2;
            curMemPos2 += (sizeof(double)*numWords);

            words = NULL;
            words = (int*)curMemPos2;
            curMemPos2 += (sizeof(int)*numWords);

            if (wordFrequency == NULL || words == NULL) {
                cout << "could not allocate memory" << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        void addwords(){
            for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
                wordFrequency[i] = i * 0.2;
            }
        }
};

int main(){ 
    curMemPos2 = (char*) malloc(1024 * 1024);

    if (curMemPos2 == NULL) {
        cout << "could not allocate initial memory" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "initializing dict with " << i << " words" << endl;
        Dictionary d = Dictionary(i);
        cout << "adding words" << endl;
        d.addwords();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on alignment.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program? Relying on a global for you class objects memory is also a bad idea/

Comment: @crashmstr better question is why are they not using `std::vector`

Comment: @Mgetz the whole `char *` array vs. the `double*` made me say that. But... ugh.

Comment: I agree that using malloc is not a good choice, sorry about that. This piece of code come from a larger project which I unfortunately have no control over.

Comment: @Daniel global state + `malloc` + lack of RAII => RUN AWAY

Comment: @Daniel - `This piece of code come from a larger project which I unfortunately have no control over`  So how are you going to fix it if you have no control over it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can adapt this specific piece of code, but other files depend on the same type of memory allocation.

Comment: @Daniel - `but other files depend on the same type of memory allocation`  So not only is the class so awfully written, it is disjointed as it isn't self contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to do a memory pool based allocator here, which isn't a bad idea in general. (The implementation could use a lot of refinement, though.)

The problem you are having is alignment. `int` is likely 4-byte aligned. `double` is likely 8-byte aligned.

The address returned by `malloc` is always suitably aligned for any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement - so it's always well-aligned for `int` or `double`. The problem occurs when you try to allocate an odd number of `int`s. Suppose `malloc` returns the address `0x3000` and you allocate five `int`s, then the address of `curMemPos2` becomes `0x3014`, and then you try to allocate five `double`s - but `0x3014` isn't a valid address for a `double` because it isn't 8-byte aligned.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Any idea as to why this only occurs for the optimized program?

Comment: @Daniel You'll have to check the assembly to be sure, presumably the compiler didn't use CPU instructions with stringent alignment requirements at lower optimization levels.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it doesn't work with optimization whereas it was working without, it the sign that there is some undefined behaviour in your code,  that in some cases (un)fortunately worked.

You have several candidates here:

- if two pointers of different type (e.g. `int *words` and `double *wordfrequency`) would point to same memory location, [strict aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) would not be respected.  Strict aliasing is about assumptions the compiler make about pointers in order to optimize code further.
- you add to your global `curMemPos2` pointer sometimes `sizeof(int)` sometimes `sizeof(double)`.  Even if your intial pointer may be compliant with all kind of alignments, it could be possible that at a moment in time your `cumMemPos2` does not comply with alignement requirements of `double` causing evil if optimizer tries to use special cpu operations with alignment requirements.
- your self made allocation scheme does not control upper bound:  you'll increment `curMemPos2` forever and your pointers might one day point to unallocated memory (nothing will set them to NULL here). But ok, this bullet is not the cause of your problem as you only allocate a couple of entries.

**Suggestions:**

As each `Dictionary` construction uses *numwords* `int` and *numwords* `double` in your self managed memory pool, I'd recommend to use a protected struct:

```
class Dictionary{
    protected: 
        struct mbloc {     // with a struct, the compiler takes care of alignment requ.
            double frequency; 
            int words; 
            };            
    public:
         ...   // allocate mbloc *entries instead of *int and *doubles; 
};
```

With this approach you could then consider using `new`  to allocate a clean array of mblocs, or perhaps even a [`vector<mbloc>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector).

Comment: `malloc` always returns addresses suitably aligned for any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement. And as written, `wordFrequency` and `words` do not point to the same memory location. This is misleading.